# Making the parallelized calculation of a bottleneck distance matrix more efficient

Tags: r, data-structures, bioinformatics, distance

I am trying to calculate a certain distance metric (called the bottleneck distance, in the package TDA) in a pairwise manner for a collection of objects I have (persistence diagrams).  I need to do this in a parallel manner on many cores, as this is quite compute intensive.  I've written this parallelized loop function to calculate the pairwise distances and place them in a matrix (using the foreach package and its parallelization capabilities):

```
CreateBottleneckDistanceMatrixParallel <- function(PD,DIM=0:2){
  print(paste0("Creating Output Matrix of Size",length(PD),"x",length(PD)))
  x <-
    foreach(b=PD, .combine='cbind') %:%
    foreach(a=PD, .combine='c') %dopar% {
      TDA::bottleneck(a,b,DIM)
    }
  x
}
```

The issue is, I know this will not be as efficient as it could be, because it will be calculating every value (a1 to b1, and then likewise b1 to a1) twice.  Is there any way I am missing that I could implement memoization to prevent the distance between a and b from being calculated again to save compute resources? Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: You could try changing indexing of the inner loop from "1:length" to "i:length".  For the first iteration of "i" it performs the operation on all elements.  For "i" =2 it skips 1 and starts at 2 to the end. etc.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I realized I simply needed to add an if statement within the inner loop so that iterations are not repeated.

```
CreateBottleneckDistanceMatrixParallel <- function(PD,DIM=0:2){
  print(paste0("Creating Output Matrix of Size",length(PD),"x",length(PD)))
  
x <- 
    foreach(i= 1:length(PD),.combine = 'cbind') %:%
    foreach(j= 1:length(PD), .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
      if (j>=i) {
        TDA::bottleneck(Diag1 = PD[[i]],Diag2 = PD[[j]], dimension = DIM)
      }
      
      else {
        NA
      }
    }
x
}
```